# SceneKit cloth physics - any solver available?

Tags: scenekit, game-physics, scnscene, cloth-simulation

How can I create cloth physics in SceneKit?

Is there a native cloth solver solution? If not, is there any other solver I could integrate with SceneKit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No and No.

Scene Kit isn't open enough to bring in a third party cloth solver and there's currently nothing like one within it.